# Is it a good idea to use unused andriod phone as a server

Tags: android, server

I got an old and unused Android phone with a 2core CPU that can run as fast as 2.6ghz and 4g of ram, which I think can suit my requirement pretty well. But the problem is should a cell phone be used as a server (will be running my own git server and database)? Or should I buy another small server, for example, a single-board computer, etc. to fit my needs? The benefit of using a cellphone is to lower the power usage and its size. But best of all, it doesn't have an additional cost. From another point of view, maintenance might not be easy.

Has anyone had this kind of experience before? Is that apt to this kind of situation?

Comment: it could be a good option. But, considering that it would be powered on almost all the time, I would suggest removing the battery.  Other than that, since the tasks you mentioned are probably not resource heavy, It's a pretty good option.

Comment: Using an Android phone on wifi as server is possible. But not with a mobile connection as most mobile providers block incoming connections.